# Output from arraylist not printing properly

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print my shuffled deck of cards, not sure what I did wrong to get null.
I am very new at java pls help (:

```
private void shuffle(PlayingCard[] valueArray)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int shuffleCount = rand.nextInt(998) + 999;

    for (int i = 0; i < shuffleCount; i++)
    {
        int cardShuffle1 = rand.nextInt(MAXD);
        int cardShuffle2 = rand.nextInt(MAXD);

        PlayingCard[]temp = new PlayingCard[1];
        temp[0] = valueArray[cardShuffle1];
        valueArray[cardShuffle1] = valueArray[cardShuffle2];


    valueArray[cardShuffle2] = temp [0];
        }
}
private void printDeck(PlayingCard[] valueArray)
    {
        System.out.println("printing from array");
        int j = 0;
        for (PlayingCard valuesArray : valueArray)
        {
            j++;
            System.out.print(valuesArray);
            if (j == MAXC)
            {
                System.out.println();
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

this is my output (first one is printing my fulldeck, the second part is supposed to be shuffled deck)

```
 print from arraylist
 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 ST SJ SQ SK SA
 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 HT HJ HQ HK HA
 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DT DJ DQ DK DA
 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CT CJ CQ CK CA

printing output from array
nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Comment: Where are you setting valueArray?
Where are you calling shuffle() and printDeck()?

Comment: That is not an ArrayList... that is an array

Comment: I tried copying your code. What is MAXD and MAXC??? WHat is your contract??

Comment: MAXC is the 13 suits of spade hearts dia clubs, maxd is the 52 playing cards

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing

```java
System.out.print(valuesArray);
```

do

```java
System.out.print(valuesArray[valuesArray]);
```

What you're doing is printing out the memory address of the array instead of its value, I think

Comment: `for (PlayingCard valuesArray : valueArray)`. He prints only 1 element of the array for each iteration as it should be

Answer (score -1):

Provide the PlayingCard.toString(..) method implementation.

Since you are printing each individual PlayingCard object from the array, I guess you implemented the toString(..) method inside the PlayingCard class.

What is that implementation. I would suggest to double check your toString(..).

Comment: public String toString()
 {
  return String.format(" %s%s", getSuit().getStrSuit(), getRank().getStrRank());
 }

Comment: I think there is more to understand from that snippet. What do those fields contain? They must be returning null.
Just for debugging purpose, print a random string like "ABC".

If you try this code:

`for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {    String s = String.format("%s%s", null, null); System.out.print(s);    }`
It will print:
`nullnullnullnull`